Is there a way to use the chartjs-plugin-annotation in the chartjs R library
I am attempting to plot some charts in chart.js using this package in R for a shiny app.
This is possible in chart JS using plugins: https://www.chartjs.org/chartjs-plugin-annotation/latest/samples/label/image.html
Is it possible to use plugins in the chartjs R implementation?
Example Image Code
https://www.example.com/image.png

Code and libraries for R chartjs example line chart
library(chartjs)
library(tidyverse)

data <- data.frame( labels = seq.Date(as.Date("2023-01-01"), 
                                      as.Date("2023-01-08"), by = 1), values = abs(rnorm(8)) )

chart <- 
  chartjs(height = "400px") %>% 
  cjsLine(labels = data$labels) %>% 
  cjsEditScale("x", 1, type = "time") %>% 
  cjsEditScale("y", 1, type = "linear") %>% 
  cjsSeries(data = data$values, label = "Sample Data") %>% 
  cjsLegend() %>% 
  cjsOptions(
    responsive = TRUE,
    title = list( display = TRUE, text = "Chart with Image Annotation" ),
    elements = list( line = list( tension = 0.000001)))

chart

There are some related answers that are able to annotate the chart with images using Javascript but I haven't seen one using the R package.
Adding images/icons to specific coordinates in chart.js
I'm attempting to get something a long the lines of this output from the chart JS website but using R, specifically the chartjs library.

It would be very good if you could provide a complete minimal, reproducible example and not just several code chunks. Also learn how to format code blocks.

Hi, please can this question be re-opened. I have edited so the code is formatted in code blocks and runs in R studio. Some related examples included as well. Hopefully this clarifies the question
